# call mmap from assembly on Macos Catalina to reserve memory

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, macos-catalina

I have an assembly file with no linked libraries on MacOs Catalina that wants to call mmap to reserve some memory dynamically. I had thought I need to do something like

```
#define __NR_mmap 0x20000c5

#define PROT_READ 0x01
#define PROT_WRITE 0x02
#define PROT_EXEC 0x04
#define PROT_ALL (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC)

#define MAP_ANON 0x1000
#define MAP_SHARED      0x0001
#define MAP_PRIVATE     0x0002

#define USER_DEFS_SIZE 0x20000

        mov $__NR_mmap, %rax            //mmap
        xor %rdi,%rdi                   // start address
        and $USER_DEFS_SIZE,%rsi        // length
        mov $PROT_READ, %rdx            // rwx
        mov $(MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED),%rcx // flags
        xor %r8,%r8                     // file descriptor
        xor %r9,%r9                     // offset
        syscall
```

but that returns 0x13 (ENODEV) in %rax. I tried passing file descriptor $-1 but that gives me an expected "bad file descriptor" error.
]

- Question1: What am I doing wrong - how do I call mmap correctly to reserve memory?
- Question2: how is the return address and errno returned? Can't rally both be in %rax, or can they? I'm unsure of the calling convention.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Is `rsi` set before this piece of code? You do `and $USER_DEFS_SIZE,%rsi`. Maybe you meant `mov`?

Comment: Yes, a stupid copy and paste mistake. Great, this seems to work now. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 3):

First, there's the problem with %rsi being uninitialized, as Jester pointed out.

After that, you've got the system call ABI wrong. The fourth argument (the flags) should be passed in `%r10`, not `%rcx`.

An error is indicated by the CF flag of the flags register. If that is set, then `%rax` contains the errno; otherwise, the return value.

Finally, I should point out that Apple specifically states that the syscall ABI may be unstable from release to release of the OS. The stable ABI is the library wrapper layer (i.e. you should call `_mmap` from libSystem.dylib). They reserve the right to break at any time anything that does syscalls directly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! regarding the ABI, are you sure ? I am not really sure I found a single canonical document. https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf says to use %rcx,  https://filippo.io/making-system-calls-from-assembly-in-mac-os-x/ says to use %r10.

Regarding the stable ABI, I agree that it's unfortunate, but since one of the main points of jonesforth is it's simplicity, I don't want to add linking to any libraries at all. I'd rather fix the syscalls in place. But thanks for pointing it out, it's good to keep that in mind and documented in the source.

Comment: @KlapauciusKlapaucius: That's the user-space function-call ABI.  The [`syscall` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) itself destroys RCX, that's why the kernel ABI has to use a different register.  The ABI doc you found describes *Linux's* system-call ABI in a separate chapter; MacOS uses something very similar but error returns are in CF instead of in-band in RAX.  (And different call numbers than Linux)

Comment: @KlapauciusKlapaucius, if you're unsure about the ABI, you can look at how the syscall library wrappers are implemented: `otool -tV /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib`. (Although `_mmap` is a little more complicated than most because it does some userland parameter checking.)

Comment: Ken, that's a great piece of advice. I never knew you can use otool to disassemble dynlibs.

BTW, do you know of an official syscall ABI documentation for darwin ? I find it hard to find any good online documentation.

Comment: I don't, sorry. The sources are online, of course, at https://opensource.apple.com/ .